# Birthdays in Contacts all one day early

Tags: calendar, contacts

Well this is a mess.

I noticed the other day that for may of my Contacts in my Apple address book, the birthday is off. I noticed this in Calendar, but it appears to be the case in Contacts as well. And it's not just on one device, but multiple (checked so far on an iPhone and Mac).

Is there any way to figure out what went wrong here, or a way to find out which ones are wrong? For a lot of the birthdays it will be hard to verify.

Comment: the date is wrong or the notification setting? I had a case (if I correctly remember) that the notification was set to 1 day before and that somehow changed it.

Comment: No, in the Contacts App itself.